# UITextView Possible to get line number?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, tokenize

Is there an easy way ie convenience method to get the line number in a textview from the position perhaps using UITokenizer?

Something like:

```
UITextView *textView =  (UITextView *)recognizer.view;
CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:textView];
CGPoint position = CGPointMake(location.x, location.y);
UITextPosition *tapPosition = [textView closestPositionToPoint:position];
UITextRange *textRange = [textView.tokenizer rangeEnclosingPosition:tapPosition withGranularity:UITextGranularityLine inDirection:UITextLayoutDirectionRight];

 (pseudocode)
int lineNumber = [textView lineNumberOf:textRange];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837348/counting-the-number-of-lines-in-a-uitextview-lines-wrapped-by-frame-size

Comment: This should get you there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807959/get-line-information-from-uitextview-and-nslayoutmanager

Comment: @ridvankucuk That's not at all what is being asked here.

Comment: I don't usually posts links to frameworks in answers, but in this case, it is rather complex to do for a UITextView. Check out this repo which can handle many different edge-cases:
https://github.com/alldritt/TextKit_LineNumbers